# How can I make a second dataframe look like a first dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes which have separate columns in them. I want the columns which are in dataframe 1 but not in 2 to be added to dataframe 2 (filled with 0's)

I wish for the remaining columns, not in dataframe 1 to be dropped from dataframe2.

I have manually done this, but I want it to be generalised for any two dataframes. I was hoping that .columns could be used however that is only usable if the dataframes have the same width.

before

```
df1
a b c d
0 1 2 3
1 2 4 5
0 1 0 1

df2
a c d e
0 2 3 0
1 3 2 1
1 0 1 0
```

after

```
df2
a b c d
0 0 2 3
1 0 3 2
1 0 0 1
```

Comment: `df2.reindex(df1.columns,axis=1,fill_value=0)`

Comment: anky that works perfectly, I can't award you the correct answer from a comment though?